# How to re re-render flat list by changing any state value?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state

I have a state

```
constructor (props) {
    super (props);
    this.state = {
      index: '',
      };
  }
```

and flatlist

```
 <FlatList
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          removeClippedSubviews={false}
          data={this.props.response}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
          renderItem={({item, index}) => this.renderFlatListItem (item, index)}
        />
```

i want to re render the flat list using  button click.
button  onPress i am changing

```
this.setState({index: 'value'});
```

i found that by setting index value the ui is rendering but  not render inside renderFlatListItem since there is no change in this.props.response;

i am looking for a solution that i want to re render flatlist view if any other state change.Let me know is it possible with react native?

Comment: Why you need rerender your list when no data change?

Comment: i am setting colour of list item depends on index.Its updating out side the list

Comment: If you really always want to force a re-render, you can give `FlatList` a `key` prop with an incrementing value, such as the current unix timestamp.

Answer (score 5):

FlatList is a PureComponent and hence doesn't re-render when none of its props change, According to the `FlatList` docs, re-renders can be caused by  passing `extraData={this.state}` to `FlatList`.

Without setting this prop, FlatList would not know it needs to re-render any items because it is also a PureComponent and the prop comparison will not show any changes. Also setting the same state state won't cause it to re-render

```
 <FlatList 
      extraData={this.state.index}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      removeClippedSubviews={false}
      data={this.props.response}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
      renderItem={({item, index}) => this.renderFlatListItem (item, index)}
    />
```

and update the state index like

```
this.setState(prevState => ({index: prevState.index + 1}));
```